How to use pyscript to generate a response to HTML dropdown selection?
I'm learning how to use pyscript. One task I want to perform is to make a response to a dropdown menu selection, such as printing out a message. However, my code below doesn't work. It shows the dropdown menu but nothing happens when I make a selection. Can you tell where I got it wrong?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Dropdown Menu Event Listener in Pyscript</h1>
    <br>
    <select id="selection">
        <option value="select">--Select--</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
  </body>   

<py-script>
from pyodide import create_proxy
runSelect = document.getElementById('selection')

def selectDropdown(event):
    selected_value = event.target.value
    if selected_value == "yes":
        print("yes")
    elif selected_value == "no":
        print("no")

proxy_select = create_proxy(selectDropdown)

runSelect.addEventListener("change", proxy_select)
</py-script>

</html>



The alpha release of PyScript is over 2 years old at this point - PyScript has come a long way since then! The most recent release as of July 2024 is 2024.7.1.
In particular, many issues with indentation were fixed in the big re-write that happened with PyScript 2023.11.1, and further in PyScript 2023.12.1 and .2.
You can see the Beginning PyScript guide for an overview of getting started with contemporary PyScript. https://docs.pyscript.net/2024.7.1/beginning-pyscript/
